# How many copies of Inkheart were printed/sold, in-universe?

Tags: inkheart-trilogy

By the time of the events of *Inkheart* (the real-world book by Cornelia Funke), physical copies of *Inkheart* (the fictional book by Fenoglio) are extremely rare - indeed, if I remember rightly, it seems that only one copy is left. It also seems that the book was never a bestseller or very successful anyway, but **how many copies were ever printed/sold?** Do we have any information about this, maybe from Fenoglio or anyone else in the story?

Comment: If this question seems confusing, talking about two books with the same name where one is real and one is fictional ... yeah, that's *Inkheart* for you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it only seems possible to put a lower limit on the number of copies of *Inkheart* that were printed. Capricorn set his men hunting down every copy they could find, taking "years to track them all down in shabby lending libraries and second-hand bookshops." To taunt his captives he burned them, to leave only one remaining copy. How many were burnt?

> In the end there were over two dozen copies of Inkheart on the piles
> of firewood, their pages crumpled, their bindings wrenched apart like
> broken wings.

As far as I can see, it is never made clear whether these were *all* the copies that Capricorn and his men ever accumulated, or whether they had previously disposed of some of them. So it seems that all we can say is that more than 24 copies existed. Given that this included foreign language translations, it seems a ridiculously small number, but it is the best we can do.

We know about several specific copies. Mo had one,
Fenoglio (the book's author) used to have five, before they were stolen:

> a lavishly illustrated special edition, a copy with a signed
> dedication by the illustrator, and the two copies that belonged to my
> own children with all their scribbled comments – I always asked them
> to mark the bits they liked best – and finally my own personal copy

and some second-hand booksellers told Elinor that they used to have some:

> A second-hand dealer from whom I buy quite often told me that three
> copies were stolen from him a few years ago. All on the same day too.
> And I’ve heard much the same story from two other booksellers.’

Apart from Mo's copy, all of these presumably ended up in the pile that was burned.